# Illustrator - Why is an illustrator file so heavy when I link images?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-size

I have 10 images (app. 6MB each) linked in my AI file. When I uncheck the "Create PDF Compatible File" option, the file is 3MB. But when I check the option (to be able to import artboards into Indesign), the file jumps to 247MB!

Any idea on how to work with high rez images and not having insanely heavy files?

Comment: Cecking a pdf compatible file makes the file a pdf file since PDF can not link it will embed no matter what you do. Dont check it. OTOH 247 MB files are small. I have a few nearly terabyte sized survey dcan files on my work disk

Comment: If not check, I cannot use artboards in my Indesign file.

Comment: Assembe the file in indesign. But 247 MB file isnt very big since a terabyte of ssd isnt really expensive these days. And one of those can hold 4000 of these files.

Comment: Raster images are embedded in the PDF version.